# YUM Update error

Tags: centos, yum, centos-6, centos-5, vps

I got a virtual machine with CentOS 6 on it. I've tried to run `yum update`, but I got this error:

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/addons/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: addons. Please verify its path and try again
```

How can I fix this. Is there any way of reinstalling Yum to revert its settings?

Answer (score 1):

The first step with things like this is to make sure yum's config has not become confused at some point, do a refresh like this:

```
yum clean all
```

Then try to run your install or update again.

But, based on the log output, it looks like your remote repository is not available at the given address, hence the 404 message.  A 404 is HTTP speak for -

> I'm the server responsible for the address you have requested, but sorry what you're asking for is not here.

This at least indicates you don't have a network connectivity problem.

Probably the best thing to do in this case, is look for an alternative mirror address for the repo, or use an alterantive repo entirely.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how do I set up an alternative mirror address?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--disablerepo=addon` helped (for example: `yum --disablerepo=addons update`) - the addons repo seems to not exist any more.

Thanks centos.org forums for the help. I've posted it as the answer to my own questions.